# How to bind Kendo Grid with System.Data.DataTable at runtime

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-4, c#-4.0, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I need to open a **Kendo Grid** in popup on Button Click. On button click server returns **DataTable** which has dynamics column (i.e. 1 to n no. of columns).On button click i get **DataTable** using **jQuery ajax** call. But I am unable to bind that data.
How to resolve this issue

Comment: please post your code what you done so far. So we can help you.

Comment: I don't have code...Please let me know, how to bind it using jquery

Comment: See my post and if you have any concern let me know. @Sandy

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try like this,

**Script**

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    $(function () {
        schmebind();
    });

    function schmebind() {
        var schemaModel = {};
        var type;
        var IsEditable = false;
        var dateColumnArray = [];

        $.each(JaiminField, function (index, da) {
            type = (da.type == undefined || da.type == 'number' || da.type == 'date') ? 'string' : da.type;
            schemaModel[da.field] = { type: type, editable: false };
            if (da.type == 'date') {
                dateColumnArray.push(da.field);
            }
        });

        var schemaModelNew = kendo.data.Model.define({
            id: "$id",
            fields: schemaModel,
            nullable: true
        });

        var knownOutagesDataSource = new kendo.data.DataSource({
            data: Jaimin,
            pageSize: 10,
            batch: true,
            schema: {
                model: schemaModelNew
            }
        });

        CreateGrid("#DynamicGrid", knownOutagesDataSource, dateColumnArray, null, null)
    }



    function CreateGrid(targetId, data, columnModel, detailTemplate, detailInit) {
        $(targetId).kendoGrid({
            dataSource: data,
            selectable: "row",
            detailTemplate: detailTemplate,
            detailInit: detailInit,
            columns: columnModel,
            filterable: false,
            sortable: true,
            dataBound: function (e) {
                if (e.sender._data.length == 0) {
                    var mgs, col;
                    mgs = "No results found for";
                    col = 9;
                    var contentDiv = this.wrapper.children(".k-grid-content"),
                 dataTable = contentDiv.children("table");
                    if (!dataTable.find("tr").length) {
                        dataTable.children("tbody").append("<tr><td colspan='" + col + "'><div style='color:red;width:500px'>" + mgs + "</div></td></tr>");
                        if (navigator.userAgent.match(/MSIE ([0-9]+)\./)) {
                            dataTable.width(this.wrapper.children(".k-grid-header").find("table").width());
                            contentDiv.scrollLeft(1);
                        }
                    }
                }
            },
            pageable: {
                previousNext: true,
                numeric: false,
                messages: {
                    empty: "No data"
                }
            },
            navigatable: true,
            scrollable: true,
            resizable: true
        });
    }
</script>
```

**View**

```
<div id="DynamicGrid">
</div>
```

**Json File**

```
var Jaimin = [
{ $id: "3", ActiveFlag: "1", CreatedBy: "Admin", TriageTypeId: 3, TriageTypeKey: "DATAUSAGE_PROVISIONING", TriageTypeName: "Data usage Provisioning", TriageTypeOrder: 3 },
{ $id: "4", ActiveFlag: "1", CreatedBy: "Admin", TriageTypeId: 4, TriageTypeKey: "DATAUSAGE_PROVISIONING", TriageTypeName: "Device Issues", TriageTypeOrder: 4 },
{ $id: "5", ActiveFlag: "1", CreatedBy: "Admin", TriageTypeId: 5, TriageTypeKey: "DATAUSAGE_PROVISIONING", TriageTypeName: "Known Outages", TriageTypeOrder: 5 },
{ $id: "6", ActiveFlag: "1", CreatedBy: "Admin", TriageTypeId: 6, TriageTypeKey: "DATAUSAGE_PROVISIONING", TriageTypeName: "Coverage", TriageTypeOrder: 6 },
{ $id: "7", ActiveFlag: "1", CreatedBy: "Admin", TriageTypeId: 7, TriageTypeKey: "DATAUSAGE_PROVISIONING", TriageTypeName: "Known Issues", TriageTypeOrder: 7 },
{ $id: "8", ActiveFlag: "1", CreatedBy: "Admin", TriageTypeId: 8, TriageTypeKey: "DATAUSAGE_PROVISIONING", TriageTypeName: "SIVR", TriageTypeOrder: 8 },
{ $id: "9", ActiveFlag: "1", CreatedBy: "Admin", TriageTypeId: 9, TriageTypeKey: "DATAUSAGE_PROVISIONING", TriageTypeName: "Grand Central - Device", TriageTypeOrder: 9 },
{ $id: "10", ActiveFlag: "1", CreatedBy: "Admin", TriageTypeId: 10, TriageTypeKey: "DATAUSAGE_PROVISIONING", TriageTypeName: "Grand Central - Coverage", TriageTypeOrder: 10 },
{ $id: "11", ActiveFlag: "1", CreatedBy: "Admin", TriageTypeId: 11, TriageTypeKey: "DATAUSAGE_PROVISIONING", TriageTypeName: "Grand Central - Account", TriageTypeOrder: 11 },
{ $id: "12", ActiveFlag: "0", CreatedBy: "Admin", TriageTypeId: 12, TriageTypeKey: "DATAUSAGE_PROVISIONING", TriageTypeName: "Network Type", TriageTypeOrder: 12 },
{ $id: "13", ActiveFlag: "1", CreatedBy: "Admin", TriageTypeId: 13, TriageTypeKey: "DATAUSAGE_PROVISIONING", TriageTypeName: "Known outages", TriageTypeOrder: 13 },
{ $id: "14", ActiveFlag: "1", CreatedBy: "Admin", TriageTypeId: 14, TriageTypeKey: "DATAUSAGE_PROVISIONING", TriageTypeName: "Local Site Issues", TriageTypeOrder: 14 },
{ $id: "15", ActiveFlag: "1", CreatedBy: "Admin", TriageTypeId: 15, TriageTypeKey: "DATAUSAGE_PROVISIONING", TriageTypeName: "Previous Complaints", TriageTypeOrder: 15 },
{ $id: "16", ActiveFlag: "1", CreatedBy: "Admin", TriageTypeId: 16, TriageTypeKey: "DATAUSAGE_PROVISIONING", TriageTypeName: "IMEI blocked", TriageTypeOrder: 16 },
{ $id: "17", ActiveFlag: "1", CreatedBy: "Admin", TriageTypeId: 17, TriageTypeKey: "DATAUSAGE_PROVISIONING", TriageTypeName: "High Speed Data Throttled", TriageTypeOrder: 17 },
{ $id: "18", ActiveFlag: "1", CreatedBy: "Admin", TriageTypeId: 18, TriageTypeKey: "DATAUSAGE_PROVISIONING", TriageTypeName: "Tethering / Hotspot Blocked", TriageTypeOrder: 18 },
{ $id: "19", ActiveFlag: "1", CreatedBy: "Admin", TriageTypeId: 19, TriageTypeKey: "DATAUSAGE_PROVISIONING", TriageTypeName: "Retrieving on-device diagnostics", TriageTypeOrder: 19 },
{ $id: "20", ActiveFlag: "1", CreatedBy: "Admin", TriageTypeId: 20, TriageTypeKey: "DATAUSAGE_PROVISIONING", TriageTypeName: "Retrieving Device Settings", TriageTypeOrder: 20 },
{ $id: "21", ActiveFlag: "1", CreatedBy: "Admin", TriageTypeId: 21, TriageTypeKey: "DATAUSAGE_PROVISIONING", TriageTypeName: "Scanning Applications", TriageTypeOrder: 21 },
{ $id: "22", ActiveFlag: "1", CreatedBy: "Admin", TriageTypeId: 22, TriageTypeKey: "DATAUSAGE_PROVISIONING", TriageTypeName: "Checking Software Version", TriageTypeOrder: 22}]



var JaiminField = [
{ field: "$id", type: "int" },
{ field: "ActiveFlag", type: "int" },
{ field: "CreatedBy", type: "string" },
{ field: "TriageTypeId", type: "int" },
{ field: "TriageTypeKey", type: "string" },
{ field: "TriageTypeName", type: "string" },
{ field: "TriageTypeOrder", type: "number" }
]
```

**Demo :** http://jsbin.com/honavive/1

If you have any concern then let me know.

Answer (score 13):

It's actually quite simple and quick too, see below:

```
@model  System.Data.DataTable

@(Html.Kendo().Grid(Model)
            .Name("DayViewGrid")
            .Columns(columns =>
              {
                  foreach (System.Data.DataColumn column in Model.Columns)
                  {
                        columns.Bound(column.ColumnName).Title(column.Caption);
                  }
              }
            )
            .Scrollable(scr => scr.Height(600))
            .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
                .Ajax()
                .Model(model =>
                     {
                         model.Id(Model.Columns[0].ColumnName);

                         foreach (System.Data.DataColumn column in Model.Columns)
                         {
                            if(column.Ordinal > 0)
                                model.Field(column.ColumnName, column.DataType);
                         }
                     }
                 )

            )
           )
```

Please let me know if this is not what you were looking for?

Comment: Thanks for reply. In my case i don't have model. I have to bind Grid using jQuery.

Comment: Create another view with the above code and call the Action to get the above view from the controller and assign the result directly to a div which will sort out your values. So what I am saying is that rather than getting DataTable return Dattable to the above new view you create and then assign the view html code to a div

Comment: @D_Learning: Excellent...you save my time

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to serialize the DataTableusing Newtonsoft.Json library. This will create the data as json string in key value pairs.

Once done, on client side bind the data to kendo grid and generate the column using the first row of data.

```
columns: generateColumns(gridData[0])


function generateColumns(firstRow)
{
 var colums = [];

        for (var property in firstRow) {
            var col = {
                field: property,
                title: property,
                width: 0,
template:""//specify your template here,
attributes:''//specify your td attributes here
               }
            colums.push(col);
        }

        return colums;
}
```

Please let me know if this help you. I can update your jsfiddle if you have any.

Comment: Thanks for reply. Can you please elaborate more?

Comment: I had the same requirement where columns are dynamic and need to be rendered in kendo grid. I would need your code to explain what changes you can do to achieve the functionality.